# What is the weight percentage of all people as compared to all Natural life?

Tags: biodiversity

If we compare the total mass  with the mass of all Naturally living beings with all creatures on Earth, be they bacteria, viruses, fish, insects, plants, etc., then what is the weight percentage of all people?

I ask this because I saw it mentioned that once people and all life they cultivated made up 0.1% of all animals and now 98%. With an exclamation mark. I am not sure if these were percentages of the total number of animals or their weight. I guess it is the number.

Comment: Why is the question downvoted? Please give a reason. I dont care about downvotes but I dont like irrational ones. Is it about the word Natural? What is Natural?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has been studied in [this paper](https://www.pnas.org/content/115/25/6506), and they came up with:

Total biomass = 550 gigatons of carbon

Human biomass = 0.06 gigatons of carbon

So this would make humans about 0.01% of all biomass.  If this sounds like a little, a couple of points are worth mentioning:

- They highlight that the mass of humans is an order of magnitude higher than that of all wild mammals combined.
- [Global human-made mass exceeds all living biomass](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-020-3010-5).  This is mostly concrete and aggregates.

[image: Graphical representation of the global biomass distribution by taxa]

Graphical representation of the global biomass distribution by taxa. (A) Absolute biomasses of different taxa are represented using a Voronoi diagram, with the area of each cell being proportional to that taxa global biomass.  (B) Absolute biomass of different animal taxa.

[image: Biomass and anthropogenic mass estimates since the beginning of the twentieth century on a dry-mass basis.]

Biomass and anthropogenic mass estimates since the beginning of the twentieth century on a dry-mass basis.

Comment: Wow! Great answer. Luckily we form a small part. For every person 100 000 kilo!

Comment: 10,000 Kg actually.

Comment: I'm surprised that livestock and humans are so close in mass. I'd thought that livestock would be higher, given the inefficiency of meat.

Comment: @jakebeal I'm sure human omnivory helps, but also that the life of livestock is so brief. Chickens are slaughtered around 6 weeks age, pigs at 6 months, beef just over a year. A dairy cow produces about 10X its weight in milk per year (though of course a lot of that is water), a hen >3X its weight in eggs.